# How can I get word wrap to work in Eclipse PDT for PHP files?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, word-wrap

Programming PHP in Eclipse PDT is predominately a joy: code completion, templates, method jumping, etc.

However, one thing that drives me crazy is that I can't get my lines in PHP files to word wrap so on long lines I'm typing out indefinitely to the right.

I click on Windows|Preferences and type in "wrap" and get:

```
- Java | Code Style | Formatter
- Java | Editor | Typing
- Web and XML | CSS Files | Source
```

I've tried changing the "wrap automatically" that I found there and the "Line width" to 72 but they had no effect.

How can I get word wrap to work in Eclipse PDT for PHP files?

Comment: I think @Fedir's answer should be the accepted answer as it has the most updated plugins

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This has really been one of the most desired features in Eclipse. It's not just missing in PHP files-- it's missing in the IDE. Fortunately, from Google Summer of Code, we get this plug-in [Eclipse Word-Wrap](http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/)

To install it, add the following update site in Eclipse:

[AhtiK Eclipse WordWrap 0.0.5 Update Site](http://ahtik.com/eclipse-update/)

Comment: Installed it in 3 minutes and now I have word-wrap, WONDERFUL, thanks.

Comment: Link is not working. Error msg : "Error establishing a database connection"

Comment: Seems his entire website is down :( hope it is temporary.

Comment: I've installed it, but it needs to be enabled it on every single page. I want to check it once for all. Someone with a similar problem ?

Comment: This plugin is not maintained and now doesn't work for newest Eclipse. Look for Fedir's answer below!

Answer (score 15):

[Eclipse Word-Wrap Plug-In](http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/word-wrap/) by Florian Weßling works well in Eclispe PDT (3.0.2).

**Installation and update sites**

*It is recommended to restart Eclipse with* `-clean` *option immediately after installation.*

Eclipse Indigo 3.7: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/indigo/
Eclipse Juno 4.2: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/juno/
Eclipse Kepler 4.3: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/kepler/
Eclipse Luna 4.4: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/luna/
Eclipse Mars 4.5: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/mars/
Eclipse Neon 4.6: Plugin not necessary.* Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> :)

<sup>* See [KrisWebDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103016/1134080) for more details and how to make word wrap permanent.</sup>

**Usage**

After the installation of the plugin:

- Context menu: *Right click* > *Toggle Word Wrap*
- Menu bar: *Edit* > *Toggle Word Wrap*
- Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>
- Also you may: *Edit* > *Activate Word Wrap in all open Editors*

There is no dedicated indicator for the current status of the word wrap setting, but you can check the horizontal scroll bar in the Editor.

- Horizontal scroll bar is visible: Word wrap is disabled.
- Horizontal scroll bar is absent: Word wrap is enabled.

Comment: This is the correct solution. The previous plugin stopped working with newest Eclipse.

Comment: Newer links: 
Eclipse Kepler 4.3: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/kepler/
Eclipse Luna 4.4: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/luna/ 
Eclipse Mars 4.5: http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/updatesite/mars/
An Eclipse restart will be required after installation.

Comment: @pgr I, J, K, L, M, N... added `:)`

Comment: @EdwardTanguay Consider accepting this answer instead, as it covers all versions from Indigo to Neon. For Neon (where word wrap is a base feature), it has a reference to KrisWebDev's answer for more detail. The current accepted answer points to a plugin that is outdated and no longer maintained - it only works with very old Eclipse versions.

Comment: @ADTC you were luckier than me. In November I tried editing the question before leaving this comment. This was rejected http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10375180 with a logic I am entirely unable to follow...

Comment: @pgr Not lucky. [Privileged ;)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) PS: I agree that the logic is 100% flawed. I would have approved your edit if I was on the panel. That link itself says: *"add addendums / updates as the post ages"* as one of the reasons you **should** edit a page.

Answer (score 10):

Finally something that works in 2016 with **native support**!

You want the latest and newer **NEON** version of Eclipse since [Bug 35779](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779) is finally patched:

- Use the [Eclipse installer](https://eclipse.org/downloads/index.php?show_instructions=TRUE)
- Click on the top right "menu" icon and choose `ADVANCED MODE`
- Select `Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers` with *Product Version*: `Latest`
- Next ... Next, Finish

Now you can toogle wordwrap manually using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for EACH file! Boring!

So if you're lucky, there's supposed to be a [nice global setting](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=257691) lost in `Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Editors` > `Text Editors` >  `Enable Wordwrap` but no, that's a trap, there's no GUI setting! At least at the time of writing.

So I've found the hard way to set it **globally** (by default):

1. Close Eclipse
2. Find `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` Eclipse settings file:

   `find ~ -name org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs -printf "%p %TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS\n"`

If you're on a platform like macOS where the above command doesn't work, you can find the settings file in your current workspace folder under `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`.

3. Add:

   `wordwrap.enabled=true`

Comment: Thanks. Confirmed working in **Eclipse for Java** as well. I think it should work with any Eclipse flavor, not limited to PHP, as it's a base feature. Mind generalizing your step 3 (select your choice of Eclipse with Product Version: `Latest (Neon)`)? Also, removing your rants would make a quality answer `;)`

Comment: This should accepted answer. At last "eclipse" has built-in "word wrap" feature.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: on windows installations, the file is in the workspace at <workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs

Answer (score 9):

It's a known enhancement request. [Bug 35779](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779)

Comment: What a shame for such an elegant IDE. :'(

Comment: Yeah, not just this, Eclipse has notoriously lacked basic editor functionalities, and it doesn't look like they care enough to do something about it (fast enough; at least they fixed something in Neon). Not just the missing word wrap functionality, the toolbar (which is a pain to manage) doesn't have Undo/Redo buttons! I have to use another plugin to add them.