# Why does the Eclipse IDE horizontal scrollbar keep resetting back to the absolute left column

Tags: eclipse, scrollbar, reset, scrollbars

I have Eclipse 3.7.1 classic, with added Android plugin and HTML editor plugin.

If I have a long line of text in the HTML editor and scroll the horizontal scrollbar to where I want to be, when I place the cursor there and start to type, after a short pause it keeps resets the horizontal scrollbar to the far left. It doesn't do it all the time, but it is frequent enough to be annoying.

Why is Eclipse doing this, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but I have the same Problem since yesterday. I don't know the cause or any solution but ende up splitting all my lengthy strings using either "\" or "+". That "fixed" the problem and resulted and better readability of the code.

Good Day
Redfox

Answer (score 0):

In my case this started happening after installing the Coffee Bytes Java Folding extension/plugin, and eventually it just annoyed me so much I turned it off...and the scroll jumping stopped.

It was a shame because I wanted folding of 'Regions' like in .Net and that extension gave me that ability. I've not looked for an alternative yet, but anyway I'm rambling - see if you have this extension enabled under Preferences > Java > Editor > Folding.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, the problem is that I'm not steady enough in my line selection.  So I'll briefly be selecting two lines of input.  And when the other line of input is shorter or even empty, it resets to the rightmost edge of that line (which if empty is the far left).  Being very careful when moving horizontally can work but is difficult to maintain.  Perhaps turning down the mouse sensitivity would help.

Searching for "eclipse line wrap" found that <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> turns line wrap on and off.  There also seems to be a button on the toolbar.  See [Does Eclipse have line-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846002/6660678) for more details.

As others have noted, changing so that the lines aren't wider than the window also fixes this.  But when you're in a situation where someone else sets the line length, toggling line wrap can be a quick and easy solution to this problem.

This of course assumes that you are having the same problem as me and not something caused by a plugin or other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Window >> Preferences >> PHP >> Editor >> Code Folding >> Enable Folding (Uncheck this)