# Configurable hard line wrapping for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, emacs, editor

Our Java code style has a *maximum line width for comments* of 255. While I'm fine with this value (I hate when automatic formatting wraps comments), I sometimes want to (hard) wrap a paragraph manually to improve readability (like the Emacs `fill-paragraph` command does):

Is there a plugin that allows to wrap a line with a specified max width, e.g. 72, similar to what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does with the *maximum line width for comments* (in my case 255)?

Note: I'm not looking for soft wrap as covered by question [Eclipse: Automatic line wrapping to specified width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241973/eclipse-automatic-line-wrapping-to-specified-width).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ain't such a plugin, as eclipse will always reformat your specific wrapped code again with CTRL-SHIFT-F.

Though at least you are able to prevent Eclipse from formatting your code & comments with a special comment: @formatter.

```
// @formatter:off

... 

// @formatter:on
```

Comment: We have now deactivated comment formatting altogether, to prevent destroying hard wrapped comments. There seems to be a bug with the 'never join line' option when there are `<p>`s in the javadoc comment...