# How do you enable word-wrap by default in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, text-editor, word-wrap, eclipse-neon

Simple question: how do you enable word-wrap by default in Eclipse? I looked at [this plugin](http://dev.cdhq.de/eclipse/word-wrap/) but it only goes up to Luna. In addition, [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/markdown-text-editor) is a separate text editor and does not have syntax highlighting or validation. I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 72):

Word wrap is available in Eclipse Neon IDE:  https://www.eclipse.org/neon/noteworthy/#_word_wrap_in_text_editors.

Just consider using the [latest version](https://eclipse.org/downloads).

Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

Or button:

[image]

Or menu Window > Editor > Toggle Word Wrap:

[image]

Comment: But as default it is disabled. When I enable it and open new file, it is disabled again.

Comment: Indeed. Please consider creating an enhancement request (via bugs.eclipse.org ) to suggest the setting to be global and propagated to all editors.

Comment: The shortcut Alt + Shift + Y works in S32 Design studio based on the eclipse framework.

Comment: I don't see this in Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: Mars 2 is seriously outdated; it's been release more than 6 years ago, and 16 major release took place since then. You won't ever get more support for it. Just drop it and use latest release.

Comment: Using STS 4, word wrap isn't listed in menus but Alt-Shift-Y works.

Answer (score 49):

As pointed out by @KrisWebDev [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103016/1134080), Eclipse supports soft line/word wrapping as of Eclipse Neon but the GUI to control this setting does not exist yet. There should be a global settings to enable soft word wrapping by default in any text editor in `Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Editors` > `Text Editors` >  `Enable Wordwrap` and it is not there.

Instead, you have to manually edit the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs` file (`.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs`) in your eclipse workspace. There, you can add the settings `wordwrap.enabled=true`.

Comment: on windows installations, the file is in the workspace at <workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs

Comment: The GUI is still not there as of Eclipse Oxygen :-/

Comment: Note that the option is not there _intentionally_ until [bug 484142](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484142) gets resolved - in short, in order to avoid potential persisting slowness, every newly editor has got the word wrap feature turned off as a workaround for now.

Comment: Thanks for the notice about the bug, I added my vote on it.

Comment: @EmmanuelGuiton This setting enables word wrap for code editors. How to permanently enable word wrap for console logs?

Comment: @neeraj I do not know if there is an option for that.

Comment: @neeraj by the way : this is another topic, you should open a new question for that.

Comment: It worked for Oxygen as of Nov 07, 2017. After adding the value in the org.eclipse.ui‌​.editors.prefs file lines were wrapped.

Comment: @neeraj You can set the preferences for Run/Debug Console to a fixed width like 120 characters. It doesn't break at word boundaries, though, it just prints exactly 120 characters and continues on the next line.

Comment: my org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs file gets overwritten at restart.  I'm using the 2021-03 edition of Eclipse

Comment: I don't see this in Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

For windows this worked for me(change workspace6 if not works), open settings file

```
%APPDATA%\DBeaverData\workspace6\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
```

add

```
wordwrap.enabled=true
```