# Word-wrap in DBeaver

Tags: word-wrap, dbeaver

Is there a way to enable word wrap as default, permanently in DBeaver? I don't want to enable it manually for every time opening new editor tab. Using version 6.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only found this github thread from 3 years ago (alongside many Eclipse related threads):
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1774

I'll update if I find a better solution. For some reason not event the hotkey works for me only the context menu.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but couldn't find mentioned files. I think there is no other solution and won't be, after three years. People should be happy without word-wrap.

Comment: I've read this post again and followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597007/how-do-you-enable-word-wrap-by-default-in-eclipse). I had missed the comment below. In windows path is different. I edited  org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs file  at "C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\"  and added "wordwrap.enabled=true". It worked. Thank you again.

Comment: I added the "wordwrap.enabled=true" to the mentioned config file but didn't work. I'm using DBeaver version 7.2.0

Answer (score 1):

[Click in a symbol like a book, select Word Wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDW58.png)

Click in a symbol like a book (Content viewer settings), select Word Wrap, it seems to work for me!